# How to show data inside conditional statement in angularjs

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs

I am using angularjs template to show data from mysql.I facing problem from to show original fetched  data inside a conditional statement.I think i am missing the correct syntax!Any help will be great.

Here is my code :

```
{{data.tran_type == 'payment' ? 'Pyament To ' : 'data.tran_type'}}
```

Comment: `{{data.tran_type == 'payment' ? 'Pyament To ' : data.tran_type}}`?

Comment: Thanks it's working but facing problem during hyperlink   {{data.tran_type=='payment' ?'Payment to':'<a href="a.php?a=data.tran_type">view</a>'}}

Comment: try `{{data.tran_type=='payment' ? 'Payment to': '<a href="a.php?a=' + data.tran_type + '">view</a>'}}`

Comment: Not working showing as plain text in browser {{data.tran_type=='payment' ? 'Payment to' : 'view'}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this one:

```
<ng-switch on="data.tran_type">
   <span ng-switch-when="payment">Payment to</span>
   <a ng-switch-default href="{{'a.php?a=' + data.tran_type}}">view</a>
</ng-switch>
```

Comment: Not working at all!Browser is reading it as a string.Showing as {{data.tran_type=='payment' ? 'Payment to' : 'view'}}